# How can I have a bracket guide when programming?

Tags: linux, programming

What I am looking for is a guide to show what area of the code a set of brackets covers. I am not referring to highlighting the match between parentheses or brackets but instead outlining the field between those brackets as show in here:

[image]

This image was taken from *Visual Studio*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's based more on indentation level than "brackets", but does [DarthFennec/highlight-indent-guides](https://github.com/DarthFennec/highlight-indent-guides) provide what you're looking for?

From the README:

> This minor mode highlights indentation levels via font-lock. Indent widths are dynamically discovered, which means this correctly highlights in any mode, regardless of indent width, even in languages with non-uniform indentation such as Haskell. By default, this mode also inspects your theme dynamically, and automatically chooses appropriate colors for highlighting. This mode works properly around hard tabs and mixed indentation, and it behaves well in large buffers.

And a sample screenshot, again from the README:

[image: screen shot from the readme]